# Where to ask about XBox 360 and Video file support?

Tags: discussion, questions

I have a question about MP4 video files and formats that I'm putting on my NAS device to share with my XBox 360 console.

The SuperUser FAQ says not to ask questions about consoles. Where is the best place on StackExchange to ask this question?

Comment: Sounds on topic on SU to me. You're more asking about console-compatible video formats, less about video-playing consoles.

Comment: @DanielBeck It also sounds on topic on SU for me

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Those questions are probably on-topic for [Gaming](http://gaming.stackexchange.com). Questions about how to actually transcode your videos to the supported formats, however, are probably not appropriate for Gaming (and are welcome on Super User).

Comment: Note, Badp is a mod on gaming, so if he says it's OK over there, then it's probably ok!